# How to filter model by system

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

When I open a 3D model in Revit, I am able to filter my views by System using System Browser.  However, when viewing the same file in autodesk viewer, I don't see an option to filter my view by System.

So, is there a way to filter model by system?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood right, the information you want is under `System Name` property. This is on the leaf level (note the model is hierarchical). So usually we start by [enumerating leaf nodes](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/enumerating-leaf-nodes-viewer).

From that you can list all systems with something like:

```
getAllLeafComponents(NOP_VIEWER, function (dbIds) {
    NOP_VIEWER.model.getBulkProperties(dbIds, ['System Name'], function(e){
        var systems = [];
        e.forEach(function(item){
            var sysName = item.properties[0].displayValue;
            if (systems.indexOf(sysName)==-1) systems.push(sysName);
        });
        console.log(systems);
    });
})
```

The `systems` array will contain the systems on the models. From that list you can `.search(systemName, cbSuccess, cbFail, ['System Name'])`, see how the last parameter indicates on which property to search.

If you already know the system name, just use this last search call...

Comment: There is no "System Name" property in the models. Sorry for not explaining it clearly, [here's an image](https://imgur.com/a/jzUr6v6) of the system browser in revit that I was trying to find after uploading and translating it in autodesk viewer.

Comment: @Kanosaki I only see that as `Type Name`, indeed no system name for this specific element... now I'm not sure if it is just this model as I can see systems on other models, and this model is a basic sample file.

Comment: I've tried other more complex models that has tons of system but after the translation process, I don't see `system name` property on any of the object's property.  From what I've noticed, the `model browser` window in `Forge Viewer` matches the `family window` in `Revit`, and in `Revit`, the object does not contain the property `System Name`.  So...I have no idea how `Revit` keep track of the systems or if the translation process actually include or dump the `Systems` .